# English pragma: legacy?

Tags: perl, pragma

In the `perl.xml` file which controls the highlighting of my editor I found a pragma named `english`. In the docu I found only a build-in module named `English`, but no `english` pragma. Is the `english` entry an error or is this some sort of legacy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a typo on the part of the makers of your editor.  The module is named `English`.  If we look back at [the earliest version of `perl` on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/~andyd/perl5.003_07/), we can see that it was named `English` back then as well.

Answer (score 2):

Either it's a typo, or your editor matches case-insensitively.

On case-insensitive file systems (e.g. NTFS on Windows), `use english;` will load the same file as `use English;`, but it won't load properly because Perl will look for `&english::import` instead of `&English::import`.